# Publish Virtual Application on IIS with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have published ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application on IIS (self-contained), It has authentication and it works fine. I need to publish another self-contained api applicationn (ASP.NET Core 5 also) in a virtual directory under the same website.

When I try to do that the main website works fine, but the application inside the virtual application, I get this error;

> "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Any idea how to configure that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why you are hosting to two application.  Seperate the API and UI. It will provide more performance.

Comment: There is only one public sub-domain available from the client.

Comment: Different asp.net core application can be published under a main site. One note is that each of them should have an independent application pool. The error you got caused by redirect. So you need to check the redirect in startup file or IIS url rewrite rule.